# service not consume message from all topic consumer group on AWS Kafka Cluster

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, kafkajs

I am very new to AWS and Kafka Cluster.

We have `NodeJs` service which connects to two different `Kafka cluster`. We have multiple instances of the consumer service and each instance consume a record from every topic but from last couple of weeks we found that service (consumers) not consuming message from every topics in list of subscribed topics, this set of topics are different every time. We have 5 different `aws` host for consumer service. When I run `describe consumer group command` I see some topics do not have any consumer attached. Every time this unassigned consumer topic list is different.

I apologies to updating question again, but while debugging the issue found this new issue.

**Code**

```
 KafkaProcessor.subscribetotopic = async (topic) => {
  const consumer = KafkaService.getConsumer(consumer);
  const message = {
   topic,
   fromBeginning: true,
  };
  await consumer.subscribe(message);
  logger.info(`Successfully subscribed to topic ${topic}`);
};

KafkaProcessor.subscribetotopiclist = async (topiclist) => {
 const promises = [];
 for (const topic of topiclist) {
  promises.push(KafkaProcessor.subscribetotopic(topic));
 }
 await Promise.all(promises);
 logger.info(`Successfully subscribed to topic ${topiclist.join()}`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to debug this issue is inspecting your consumer groups using ConsumerGroupCommand tool. This will give you the better glimpse of your consumer instances.

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

--**members** --**verbose**: On top of the information reported by the "--members" options above, this option also provides the partitions assigned to each member.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group --members

bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group --members –verbose
```

Comment: Hi ChrisDist, thank you for the response. I ran above command and find that, under CONSUMER-ID column I see only 3 consumers and 2 others are failed to connect. Not sure why they failed. Do you have any pointer how to proceed to check why it is failing.

Comment: Would you be able to check and provide the consumer logs from the failed ones. There may be some recent upgrade they preventing your consumers to connect to the brokers. You even can perform some connectivity test to your broker.

Comment: @ppb The only way to debug is to add more logging into the consumer applications and restart them manually

Comment: Hi ChrisDist, In consumer logs I see there is connection failure for consumer, but I am not sure in between the application running why connection failed for consumers. We are using `kafkjs` library. Is it because of consumers not able send heartbeat to broker and broker removing consumer from group?  Can I increase `sessionTimeout`